# How to refresh page after success message in angular 2

Tags: angular

I have been trying to display success message and refresh my page after I perform an action. Let's say when I perform a delete operation, response from the backend should display on the page and refresh afterwards. How do I go about that please?

```
reloadGame() {
   this.gameService.getAllGames().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data)
   })
}

removeGame(game) {
   this.httpService.deleteGame(game.id).subscribe(data => {
      this.reloadGame()
   })
}
```

Comment: What is the issue with this code? Post your error/issue

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "refresh the page"? Do you want to trigger a hard page reload (like when you hit the browser reload button)? Or just clear a status message?

Comment: @AliBaig, there is no error in the console but after i delete a game, i expect the page to display the response from the backend and also refresh the page. i am trying to refresh with the reloadGame function.  The success Response also shows correctly in the console but not on the page

Comment: Post your page code as well! This seems okay to me!

Comment: @AngularFrance, i don't know if i am making enough sense by saying reload but aparently, i want the page to refresh or let me say update when i perform a delete operation

Comment: You're saying you want to reload the data to reflect the fact that something has been deleted?

Comment: @AngularFrance, exactly.. Just after the success message displays

Comment: @AliBaig i have added the page

Comment: What's wrong with the code you posted? Looks like it could work the way it is.

Comment: @Switz Seems like you have forgot to assign the response returned by the service, see the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could have a message string assign it the message in subscribe before this.reloadGame() and in the subscribe of reloadGame again make it null.

and in html

```
<div *ngIf="message" class="success">{{message}}<div>
```

Comment: you could also put some delay before assigning message to null

Answer (score 0):

```
private Games:any = [];   //assuming your have an array called Games
```

You need to set the response returned by the service to the variable that's bound to your HTML.

```
reloadGame(){
 this.gameService.getAllGames()
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.Games = data;       <== You have not set the response to your Games array
    });
}
```

This should work with the following HTML

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let game of Games; let i = index">
         <td>{{i + 1}}</td>
         <td>{{game.name}}</td>
         <td>{{game.type}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>    
</table>
```

Comment: After i delete, it doesn't refresh to show the update instead i have to hit on the browsers reload before i see the change

Comment: Have you tried the changes mentioned above? Are you sure the service `this.gameService.getAllGames()` is returning the updated results?

Comment: What does your service return, a string or objects? See `data` in your subscribe and post here.

Comment: when i look in the network tab of my browser,  i see the delete operation is done and after the games is fetched back . But my page does not refresh until i press the reload button

Answer (score 0):

I know it's quite long time ago since you post the question, but i hope this could help other who need the same solution...anyway....

Just put javascript code such as location.reload(); 
or if you want to use angular style just put this.ngOnInit(); on the ts file of the page you want to reload/refresh.

```
reloadGame() {
   this.gameService.getAllGames().subscribe(data => {
       console.log(data)
       location.reload();  //Add this line to your code option 1
       this.ngOnInit();    //or you could add this also as option 2 instead using option 1
   })
}

removeGame(game) {
   this.httpService.deleteGame(game.id).subscribe(data => {
       this.reloadGame()
   })
}
```